# XNA Platformer Collision: PerPixel vs Rectangle

Tags: xna, collision-detection

I'm writing a platformer engine with XNA and was wondering what method for handling collisions I should use. Would I be seeing some performance issues if I were to try and have PerPixel collisions? Should I be using per pixel collision handling or rectangle collision handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, per pixel collision detection is much more expensive; so as much as possible, use rectangle collision handling. (Even for per-pixel, use rectangles first to check for overlap.) When I implemented collision detection in [Radiant Wrench](http://www.radiantwrench.com), this is precisely what I used.

Alternatively, you can try [Flat Red Ball](http://flatredball.com) (which I used to use before), which uses polygons for detection (which is quite performant). You can use basic types (rectangle/circle) or create your own polygon from verticies. They don't support per-pixel collisions though.

Comment: Hmmm, yes I see... Would the performance still be an issue if I used rectangles first to check for an overlap? I'm thinking maybe I will only use per pixel collision for things like attacks and maybe enemies.

Comment: The golden rule of performance is "don't worry about performance until you see a bottleneck happen." You *have* to use rectangles first, there's no real alternative. Rectangle bounds checking is very very trivial (because it doesn't support rotation).

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have specific questions about collision detection later.

Comment: @ashes999 "don't worry about performance until you see a bottleneck happen." - and thats the reason why there is so much of unoptimized software when hardware is so cheap right

Comment: @Tomas right. Hardware scales easily. Also, this is why we have so much slow software -- it was "optimized" by someone who didn't know the first thing about optimization.